# Woocommerce shop and product pages are altering my css

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to set up and online shop on using Woocommerce. I am using a custom theme so have not used and wootheme. I am having problems with styling on the shop (archive-product.php) and the individual product (content-single-product.php) pages. The css is loading but for some reason is not having an effect. The styling is fine for all other pages e.g. checkout, cart etc. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thank-you.

Comment: Do you have a link of where this is happening? It might be that the style on the shop pages are being overridden with styles from woocommerce.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The style is not crossed out but is just having no effect. It shows up when I inspect element in the browser but has no effect.

Comment: This is not a css issue but an issue with theme conflict. See http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/